# REACT JSX - Error al compilar "Object" is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

soy muy nuevo en el mundo del JavaScript y sobre todo en el de React.
Estoy tratando de probar mis conocimientos con algunos retos, pero en este caso no sé qué hacer.

En resumidas cuentas, tengo una API de super héroes la cual me provee un Json que se renderiza en una cuadricula en la mitad de la pantalla mediante el método MAP, hasta ahí va todo bien, pero después de eso quiero que en la otra mitad de la pantalla se muestre la información de ese objeto cliqueado, cree la función `mostrar()` la cuál contiene lo siguiente:

```
const h1 = <h1>{heroes.name}</h1>
document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = h1
```

El problema es que me dice que "heroes" de la función `mostrar()` no está definido.

Adjunto el código:

```
class TablaDeHeroes extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = { 
        heroes: [],
        isFetch: true,
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
 fetch("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/akabab/superhero-api@0.3.0/api/all.json")
    .then( Response => Response.json())
    .then(heroesJson => this.setState({heroes: heroesJson, isFetch: false}))
}

render() { 
    const heroe = this.state.heroes

    if (this.state.isFetch) {return (<div className="cargando"><h1>Cargando...</h1></div>)}

    function mostrar() {
        const h1 = <h1>{heroes.name}</h1>
        document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = h1
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            {heroe.slice(0, 20).map(heroes => 
                    <div className="tarjetaHeroe" key={heroes.id} onClick={mostrar()}>
                        <h1> {heroes.name} </h1>
                        <div className="sombra"></div>
                        <img className="imgHeroeMini" src={heroes.images.lg} alt={heroes.name}/>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

Agradecería mucho la ayuda, realmente me ayudaría muchísimo a seguir mejorando y si me quieren recomendar algún curos o algo por el estilo es más que bienvenido.

GRACIAS!

Comment: en la función `mostrar` le envías `heroes`? o exactamente donde te muestra el error?

Comment: @Richard el error proviene de la función `mostrar`, específicamente de la constante h1 `<h1>{heroes.name}</h1>`

Answer (score 1):

Veo 2 posibles problemas en tu código

1. Tu tienes declarado `onClick={mostrar()}` lo cual ocasiona que se
   ejecute `mostrar` al inicio, aun sin dar un `click`. Recomiendo que
   este de esta manera.

   ```
   onClick={mostrar}
   ```
2. intentas insertar en `div1` tal cual se realizaría en `javaScript` sin utilizar `reactjs`, lo cual no estoy seguro que funcione. Sugiero que utilices el `estate` para saber la selección actual del **heroe**

---

### Agregar al estado la selección

Debe quedar mas o menos de la siguiente manera tu estado

```
this.state = { 
    heroes: [],
    isFetch: true,
    seleccion: {name:'', poder:''}
}
```

### actualizar el estado

hay varias formas de actualizar el estado, una de ellas es la siguiente

```
mostrar() {
    const newHeroe = {name:'Nuevo nombre', poder:'Nuevo poder'};
    this.setState({seleccion:newHeroe});
}
```

---

Todo el manejo de estados se vuelve mucho mas fácil con los **hooks**, lo cual puedes revisarlo en la [documentación](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que no estás llamando bien al objeto `heroes`. Ni dentro de la función ni tampoco las otras veces que lo usas.

Como estás usando la antigua versión de React que trabaja con componentes de clases, cada vez que uses un objeto que está definido en el estado (lo que se define dentro del `constructor()` y `super()`) deberías llamarlo luego así: `this.state.heroes`. Como ya estás haciendo con el `this.state.isFetch` que está dentro del `if()`.

Otro detalle importante es que al utilizar React no se necesita usar el `document.getElementById().innerHTML` para renderizar contenido dinámico al DOM.

Como React utiliza `JSX` basta con poner el contenido dinámico simplemente entre llaves `{}`. Como también ya estás haciendo con `heroes` dentro del `.map`.